# Regex strip <a> tags containing certain href value

Tags: php, regex

I am not good at regex.

I got this string with some html `<a>` tags and i need to strip some of them out, but only `<a>` tags containing a certain value in the "href" attribut (mysite.com).

I still need to keep the link text, like the php function `strip_tags($string, "<a>")`

Here is what I got so far.:

```
/<a href=["\']?(http:\/\/mysite.com[^"\'\s>]+)["\'\s>]?/i
```

This is also working, but the problem is that I can't get the "text" in fx. `<a href="http://mysite.com/testing/something">"text"</a>`

**So the input.:**

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="http://mysite.com/testing/something">dolor</a> sit amet, <a href="http://keepingThisLink.com">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Duis dignissim <a href="http://mysite.com/testing">golor</a> vitae turpis fermentum tincidunt.
```

**Should output.:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://keepingThisLink.com">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Duis dignissim golor vitae turpis fermentum tincidunt.
```

Comment: What would happen if you had an a tag `<a class="someclass" href="url">` or `<a id="someid" href="url">`? You can't parse HTML with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more reliable, DOM-based approach:

```
<?php

$a = 'Lorem ipsum <a href="http://mysite.com/testing/something">dolor</a> sit amet, <a href="http://keepingThisLink.com">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Duis dignissim <a href="http://mysite.com/testing">golor</a> vitae turpis fermentum tincidunt.';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($a);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach ($domx->query("//a") as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute("href");
    if ($href === "http://keepingThisLink.com") {
        continue;
    }

    $text = $domd->createTextNode($link->nodeValue);

    $link->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $link);
}

//unfortunately saveHTML adds doctype and a few unneccessary tags    
var_dump(preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $domd->saveHTML())));
```

the output is:

```
string(161) "
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://keepingThisLink.com">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Duis dignissim golor vitae turpis fermentum tincidunt.</p>
"
```

Comment: You don't have to generate an entire DOM document with saveHTML.  If you pass in a DOMElement object as an argument, saveHTML will render just this element (you could pass in a DOMElement representing the containing `<p>` tag for example)

Comment: The documentation says so, but when I tried that, it errored. See [this php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39771). I tested the above code on 5.3.5.

Comment: Thanks - this could work but preg_replace does not work with special characters for example.: `&aelig;`, `å`, `&egrave;`, `è` :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the problem that domdocument converts special characters to html entities?

Comment: Fx.  with the input `$a = 'Lorem &egrave; and è ipsum  <a href="http://mysite.com/testing/something">dolor</a> sit amet, <a href="http://keepingThisLink.com">consectetur</a>';`

Comment: You need to make sure your input is in utf-8. You can also explicitly tell domdocument that the contents are in utf8 like `$domd = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");`

Comment: @Maerlyn I just went back and double-checked some previous code I'd written that uses saveHTML(DOMElement) and it works just fine here.  The DOMElement has to be a descendant of the DOMDocument you're using to render it, but otherwise it works just like the docs say it should.

Comment: Apparently it has been fixed in 5.3.6, that's why when I tested it in 5.3.5 I got a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at PHP's DOM classes, they'll let you locate all the hyperlinks within a HTML document, get their href attributes and update/remove them in a way that's far more robust than attempting to do it with regex.

(Please note that the following example is "from the hip" and hasn't been tested)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument ();

// Load from a file
$dom -> load ('/path/to/my/file.html');

// Or load a HTML string
$dom -> loadHTML ($string);

// Or load an XHTML string as XML
$dom -> loadXML ($string);

// Find all the hyperlinks
if ($nodes = $dom -> getElementsByTagName ('a'))
{
    foreach ($nodes as $node)
    {
        var_dump ($node -> getAttribute ('href'));
    }
}
```